# How to make appendix on revealjs rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, reveal.js

I would like to include an appendix after the references on my Rmd file. With HTML output this would imply the following specification:

```
pandoc_args: ["--include-after-body=appendix.md"]
```

However, if I do it with the revealjs engine this does not work

```
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    pandoc_args: ["--include-after-body=appendix.md"]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put

```
# References

<div id="refs"></div>

# Appendix
```